# Windows Form Cut Copy Paste Shortcut key

Tags: winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a windowsform application. I have implemented Cut Copy Paste Functionality. But I am unable to assign the standard shortcut for the same
Ctrl+C, Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V. If however I assign other shortcut keys like Ctrl+J then the shortcut works. 
How to assign Ctrl+C to the Copy function?

Comment: How do you assign the shortcuts?

Comment: What control are we taking about? textbox for example have copy paste functionality out-of-the-box.

Comment: @tzup I have Menu items to which I have assigned short-cuts. @Jeremy yeas textbox. I know they have the Copy paste functionality, what I am looking for is to implement shortcut keys to menu items for Cut Copy Paste

Comment: verify if your shortcuts are not already assigned to other controls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really surprised that this question doesn't come up more often or have a simple, straightforward FAQ answer.  Anyhow, I was searching for the same need and eventually found these 2 resources with possible solutions...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/TcMagicalEditMenu.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/7a42a16e-e8b8-4425-a91e-a048d81d4ab4

Comment: Well, the samples show how to cut, cop, paste from Active cntrol. That part I have already implemented. What I want to know is how to assign the shortcuts.